# NormalizeUtf8 error when loading tensorflow model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

i created a new tensorflow neural machine translation model using this code(in jupyter notebook):

```
import numpy as np

import typing
from typing import Any, Tuple

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_text as tf_text

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

use_builtins = True

#@title Shape checker
class ShapeChecker():
  def __init__(self):
    # Keep a cache of every axis-name seen
    self.shapes = {}

  def __call__(self, tensor, names, broadcast=False):
    if not tf.executing_eagerly():
      return

    if isinstance(names, str):
      names = (names,)

    shape = tf.shape(tensor)
    rank = tf.rank(tensor)

    if rank != len(names):
      raise ValueError(f'Rank mismatch:\n'
                       f'    found {rank}: {shape.numpy()}\n'
                       f'    expected {len(names)}: {names}\n')

    for i, name in enumerate(names):
      if isinstance(name, int):
        old_dim = name
      else:
        old_dim = self.shapes.get(name, None)
      new_dim = shape[i]

      if (broadcast and new_dim == 1):
        continue

      if old_dim is None:
        # If the axis name is new, add its length to the cache.
        self.shapes[name] = new_dim
        continue

      if new_dim != old_dim:
        raise ValueError(f"Shape mismatch for dimension: '{name}'\n"
                         f"    found: {new_dim}\n"
                         f"    expected: {old_dim}\n")
# Download the file
import pathlib

path_to_file = pathlib.Path('data.txt')
def load_data(path):
  text = path.read_text(encoding='utf-8')

  lines = text.splitlines()
  pairs = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]

  inp = [inp for targ, inp in pairs]
  targ = [targ for targ, inp in pairs]

  return targ, inp

targ, inp = load_data(path_to_file)
print(inp[-1])
print(targ[-1])
BUFFER_SIZE = len(inp)
BATCH_SIZE = 64

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inp, targ)).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
for example_input_batch, example_target_batch in dataset.take(1):
  print(example_input_batch[:5])
  print()
  print(example_target_batch[:5])
  break

example_text = tf.constant('“Энэхүү вакциныг аюулгүй гэдгийг бид мэдэж байгаа учраас нэмэлт тунд хамрагдсан хүүүхдүүдийн тоог үргэлжлүүлэн нэмэгдүүлэх хэрэгтэй” гэж тэрбээр хэлжээ.')

print(example_text.numpy())
print(tf_text.normalize_utf8(example_text, 'NFKD').numpy())

def tf_lower_and_split_punct(text):
  # Split accecented characters.
  text = tf_text.normalize_utf8(text, 'NFKD')
  # Keep space, a to z, and select punctuation.
  # Add spaces around punctuation.
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '[.?!,¿]', r' \0 ')
  # Strip whitespace.
  text = tf.strings.strip(text)

  text = tf.strings.join(['[START]', text, '[END]'], separator=' ')
  return text

print(example_text.numpy().decode())
print(tf_lower_and_split_punct(example_text).numpy().decode())

max_vocab_size = 5000

input_text_processor = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=tf_lower_and_split_punct,
    max_tokens=max_vocab_size)

input_text_processor.adapt(inp)

# Here are the first 10 words from the vocabulary:
input_text_processor.get_vocabulary()[:10]

output_text_processor = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=tf_lower_and_split_punct,
    max_tokens=max_vocab_size)

output_text_processor.adapt(targ)
output_text_processor.get_vocabulary()[:10]

example_tokens = input_text_processor(example_input_batch)
example_tokens[:3, :10]

input_vocab = np.array(input_text_processor.get_vocabulary())
tokens = input_vocab[example_tokens[0].numpy()]
' '.join(tokens)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.pcolormesh(example_tokens)
plt.title('Token IDs')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.pcolormesh(example_tokens != 0)
plt.title('Mask')

embedding_dim = 256
units = 1024

class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, input_vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.enc_units = enc_units
    self.input_vocab_size = input_vocab_size

    # The embedding layer converts tokens to vectors
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.input_vocab_size,
                                               embedding_dim)

    # The GRU RNN layer processes those vectors sequentially.
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.enc_units,
                                   # Return the sequence and state
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

  def call(self, tokens, state=None):
    shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
    shape_checker(tokens, ('batch', 's'))

    # 2. The embedding layer looks up the embedding for each token.
    vectors = self.embedding(tokens)
    shape_checker(vectors, ('batch', 's', 'embed_dim'))

    # 3. The GRU processes the embedding sequence.
    #    output shape: (batch, s, enc_units)
    #    state shape: (batch, enc_units)
    output, state = self.gru(vectors, initial_state=state)
    shape_checker(output, ('batch', 's', 'enc_units'))
    shape_checker(state, ('batch', 'enc_units'))

    # 4. Returns the new sequence and its state.
    return output, state

# Convert the input text to tokens.
example_tokens = input_text_processor(example_input_batch)

# Encode the input sequence.
encoder = Encoder(input_text_processor.vocabulary_size(),
                  embedding_dim, units)
example_enc_output, example_enc_state = encoder(example_tokens)

print(f'Input batch, shape (batch): {example_input_batch.shape}')
print(f'Input batch tokens, shape (batch, s): {example_tokens.shape}')
print(f'Encoder output, shape (batch, s, units): {example_enc_output.shape}')
print(f'Encoder state, shape (batch, units): {example_enc_state.shape}')

class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super().__init__()
    # For Eqn. (4), the  Bahdanau attention
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, use_bias=False)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, use_bias=False)

    self.attention = tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention()

  def call(self, query, value, mask):
    shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
    shape_checker(query, ('batch', 't', 'query_units'))
    shape_checker(value, ('batch', 's', 'value_units'))
    shape_checker(mask, ('batch', 's'))

    # From Eqn. (4), `W1@ht`.
    w1_query = self.W1(query)
    shape_checker(w1_query, ('batch', 't', 'attn_units'))

    # From Eqn. (4), `W2@hs`.
    w2_key = self.W2(value)
    shape_checker(w2_key, ('batch', 's', 'attn_units'))

    query_mask = tf.ones(tf.shape(query)[:-1], dtype=bool)
    value_mask = mask

    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(
        inputs = [w1_query, value, w2_key],
        mask=[query_mask, value_mask],
        return_attention_scores = True,
    )
    shape_checker(context_vector, ('batch', 't', 'value_units'))
    shape_checker(attention_weights, ('batch', 't', 's'))

    return context_vector, attention_weights

attention_layer = BahdanauAttention(units)

(example_tokens != 0).shape

# Later, the decoder will generate this attention query
example_attention_query = tf.random.normal(shape=[len(example_tokens), 2, 10])

# Attend to the encoded tokens

context_vector, attention_weights = attention_layer(
    query=example_attention_query,
    value=example_enc_output,
    mask=(example_tokens != 0))

print(f'Attention result shape: (batch_size, query_seq_length, units):           {context_vector.shape}')
print(f'Attention weights shape: (batch_size, query_seq_length, value_seq_length): {attention_weights.shape}')

class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, output_vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.dec_units = dec_units
    self.output_vocab_size = output_vocab_size
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim

    # For Step 1. The embedding layer convets token IDs to vectors
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.output_vocab_size,
                                               embedding_dim)

    # For Step 2. The RNN keeps track of what's been generated so far.
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.dec_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

    # For step 3. The RNN output will be the query for the attention layer.
    self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.dec_units)

    # For step 4. Eqn. (3): converting `ct` to `at`
    self.Wc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dec_units, activation=tf.math.tanh,
                                    use_bias=False)

    # For step 5. This fully connected layer produces the logits for each
    # output token.
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.output_vocab_size)

class DecoderInput(typing.NamedTuple):
  new_tokens: Any
  enc_output: Any
  mask: Any

class DecoderOutput(typing.NamedTuple):
  logits: Any
  attention_weights: Any
def call(self,
         inputs: DecoderInput,
         state=None) -> Tuple[DecoderOutput, tf.Tensor]:
  shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
  shape_checker(inputs.new_tokens, ('batch', 't'))
  shape_checker(inputs.enc_output, ('batch', 's', 'enc_units'))
  shape_checker(inputs.mask, ('batch', 's'))

  if state is not None:
    shape_checker(state, ('batch', 'dec_units'))

  # Step 1. Lookup the embeddings
  vectors = self.embedding(inputs.new_tokens)
  shape_checker(vectors, ('batch', 't', 'embedding_dim'))

  # Step 2. Process one step with the RNN
  rnn_output, state = self.gru(vectors, initial_state=state)

  shape_checker(rnn_output, ('batch', 't', 'dec_units'))
  shape_checker(state, ('batch', 'dec_units'))

  # Step 3. Use the RNN output as the query for the attention over the
  # encoder output.
  context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(
      query=rnn_output, value=inputs.enc_output, mask=inputs.mask)
  shape_checker(context_vector, ('batch', 't', 'dec_units'))
  shape_checker(attention_weights, ('batch', 't', 's'))

  # Step 4. Eqn. (3): Join the context_vector and rnn_output
  #     [ct; ht] shape: (batch t, value_units + query_units)
  context_and_rnn_output = tf.concat([context_vector, rnn_output], axis=-1)

  # Step 4. Eqn. (3): `at = tanh(Wc@[ct; ht])`
  attention_vector = self.Wc(context_and_rnn_output)
  shape_checker(attention_vector, ('batch', 't', 'dec_units'))

  # Step 5. Generate logit predictions:
  logits = self.fc(attention_vector)
  shape_checker(logits, ('batch', 't', 'output_vocab_size'))

  return DecoderOutput(logits, attention_weights), state

Decoder.call = call

decoder = Decoder(output_text_processor.vocabulary_size(),
                    embedding_dim, units)

# Convert the target sequence, and collect the "[START]" tokens
example_output_tokens = output_text_processor(example_target_batch)

start_index = output_text_processor.get_vocabulary().index('[START]')
first_token = tf.constant([[start_index]] * example_output_tokens.shape[0])

# Run the decoder
dec_result, dec_state = decoder(
    inputs = DecoderInput(new_tokens=first_token,
                          enc_output=example_enc_output,
                          mask=(example_tokens != 0)),
    state = example_enc_state
)

print(f'logits shape: (batch_size, t, output_vocab_size) {dec_result.logits.shape}')
print(f'state shape: (batch_size, dec_units) {dec_state.shape}')

sampled_token = tf.random.categorical(dec_result.logits[:, 0, :], num_samples=1)

vocab = np.array(output_text_processor.get_vocabulary())
first_word = vocab[sampled_token.numpy()]
first_word[:5]

dec_result, dec_state = decoder(
    DecoderInput(sampled_token,
                 example_enc_output,
                 mask=(example_tokens != 0)),
    state=dec_state)

sampled_token = tf.random.categorical(dec_result.logits[:, 0, :], num_samples=1)
first_word = vocab[sampled_token.numpy()]
first_word[:5]

class MaskedLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'masked_loss'
    self.loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
        from_logits=True, reduction='none')

  def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):
    shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
    shape_checker(y_true, ('batch', 't'))
    shape_checker(y_pred, ('batch', 't', 'logits'))

    # Calculate the loss for each item in the batch.
    loss = self.loss(y_true, y_pred)
    shape_checker(loss, ('batch', 't'))

    # Mask off the losses on padding.
    mask = tf.cast(y_true != 0, tf.float32)
    shape_checker(mask, ('batch', 't'))
    loss *= mask

    # Return the total.
    return tf.reduce_sum(loss)

class TrainTranslator(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, embedding_dim, units,
               input_text_processor,
               output_text_processor, 
               use_tf_function=True):
    super().__init__()
    # Build the encoder and decoder
    encoder = Encoder(input_text_processor.vocabulary_size(),
                      embedding_dim, units)
    decoder = Decoder(output_text_processor.vocabulary_size(),
                      embedding_dim, units)

    self.encoder = encoder
    self.decoder = decoder
    self.input_text_processor = input_text_processor
    self.output_text_processor = output_text_processor
    self.use_tf_function = use_tf_function
    self.shape_checker = ShapeChecker()

  def train_step(self, inputs):
    self.shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
    if self.use_tf_function:
      return self._tf_train_step(inputs)
    else:
      return self._train_step(inputs)

def _train_step(self, inputs):
  input_text, target_text = inputs  

  (input_tokens, input_mask,
   target_tokens, target_mask) = self._preprocess(input_text, target_text)

  max_target_length = tf.shape(target_tokens)[1]

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Encode the input
    enc_output, enc_state = self.encoder(input_tokens)
    self.shape_checker(enc_output, ('batch', 's', 'enc_units'))
    self.shape_checker(enc_state, ('batch', 'enc_units'))

    # Initialize the decoder's state to the encoder's final state.
    # This only works if the encoder and decoder have the same number of
    # units.
    dec_state = enc_state
    loss = tf.constant(0.0)

    for t in tf.range(max_target_length-1):
      # Pass in two tokens from the target sequence:
      # 1. The current input to the decoder.
      # 2. The target for the decoder's next prediction.
      new_tokens = target_tokens[:, t:t+2]
      step_loss, dec_state = self._loop_step(new_tokens, input_mask,
                                             enc_output, dec_state)
      loss = loss + step_loss

    # Average the loss over all non padding tokens.
    average_loss = loss / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(target_mask, tf.float32))

  # Apply an optimization step
  variables = self.trainable_variables 
  gradients = tape.gradient(average_loss, variables)
  self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

  # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
  return {'batch_loss': average_loss}

def _loop_step(self, new_tokens, input_mask, enc_output, dec_state):
  input_token, target_token = new_tokens[:, 0:1], new_tokens[:, 1:2]

  # Run the decoder one step.
  decoder_input = DecoderInput(new_tokens=input_token,
                               enc_output=enc_output,
                               mask=input_mask)

  dec_result, dec_state = self.decoder(decoder_input, state=dec_state)
  self.shape_checker(dec_result.logits, ('batch', 't1', 'logits'))
  self.shape_checker(dec_result.attention_weights, ('batch', 't1', 's'))
  self.shape_checker(dec_state, ('batch', 'dec_units'))

  # `self.loss` returns the total for non-padded tokens
  y = target_token
  y_pred = dec_result.logits
  step_loss = self.loss(y, y_pred)

  return step_loss, dec_state

TrainTranslator._loop_step = _loop_step

translator = TrainTranslator(
    embedding_dim, units,
    input_text_processor=input_text_processor,
    output_text_processor=output_text_processor,
    use_tf_function=False)

# Configure the loss and optimizer
translator.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=MaskedLoss(),
)

np.log(output_text_processor.vocabulary_size())

%%time
for n in range(10):
  print(translator.train_step([example_input_batch, example_target_batch]))
print()

@tf.function(input_signature=[[tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None]),
                               tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])]])
def _tf_train_step(self, inputs):
  return self._train_step(inputs)

TrainTranslator._tf_train_step = _tf_train_step

translator.use_tf_function = True

translator.train_step([example_input_batch, example_target_batch])

%%time
for n in range(10):
  print(translator.train_step([example_input_batch, example_target_batch]))
print()

losses = []
for n in range(100):
  print('.', end='')
  logs = translator.train_step([example_input_batch, example_target_batch])
  losses.append(logs['batch_loss'].numpy())

print()
plt.plot(losses)

train_translator = TrainTranslator(
    embedding_dim, units,
    input_text_processor=input_text_processor,
    output_text_processor=output_text_processor)

# Configure the loss and optimizer
train_translator.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=MaskedLoss(),
)

class BatchLogs(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key
    self.logs = []

  def on_train_batch_end(self, n, logs):
    self.logs.append(logs[self.key])

batch_loss = BatchLogs('batch_loss')

train_translator.fit(dataset, epochs=1,
                     callbacks=[batch_loss])


plt.plot(batch_loss.logs)
plt.ylim([0, 3])
plt.xlabel('Batch #')
plt.ylabel('CE/token')

class Translator(tf.Module):

  def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, input_text_processor,
               output_text_processor):
    self.encoder = encoder
    self.decoder = decoder
    self.input_text_processor = input_text_processor
    self.output_text_processor = output_text_processor

    self.output_token_string_from_index = (
        tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
            vocabulary=output_text_processor.get_vocabulary(),
            mask_token='',
            invert=True))

    # The output should never generate padding, unknown, or start.
    index_from_string = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=output_text_processor.get_vocabulary(), mask_token='')
    token_mask_ids = index_from_string(['', '[UNK]', '[START]']).numpy()

    token_mask = np.zeros([index_from_string.vocabulary_size()], dtype=np.bool)
    token_mask[np.array(token_mask_ids)] = True
    self.token_mask = token_mask

    self.start_token = index_from_string(tf.constant('[START]'))
    self.end_token = index_from_string(tf.constant('[END]'))

translator = Translator(
    encoder=train_translator.encoder,
    decoder=train_translator.decoder,
    input_text_processor=input_text_processor,
    output_text_processor=output_text_processor,
)


def tokens_to_text(self, result_tokens):
  shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
  shape_checker(result_tokens, ('batch', 't'))
  result_text_tokens = self.output_token_string_from_index(result_tokens)
  shape_checker(result_text_tokens, ('batch', 't'))

  result_text = tf.strings.reduce_join(result_text_tokens,
                                       axis=1, separator=' ')
  shape_checker(result_text, ('batch'))

  result_text = tf.strings.strip(result_text)
  shape_checker(result_text, ('batch',))
  return result_text

example_output_tokens = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[5, 2], minval=0, dtype=tf.int64,
    maxval=output_text_processor.vocabulary_size())
translator.tokens_to_text(example_output_tokens).numpy()


def sample(self, logits, temperature):
  shape_checker = ShapeChecker()
  # 't' is usually 1 here.
  shape_checker(logits, ('batch', 't', 'vocab'))
  shape_checker(self.token_mask, ('vocab',))

  token_mask = self.token_mask[tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]
  shape_checker(token_mask, ('batch', 't', 'vocab'), broadcast=True)

  # Set the logits for all masked tokens to -inf, so they are never chosen.
  logits = tf.where(self.token_mask, -np.inf, logits)

  if temperature == 0.0:
    new_tokens = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
  else: 
    logits = tf.squeeze(logits, axis=1)
    new_tokens = tf.random.categorical(logits/temperature,
                                        num_samples=1)
  
  shape_checker(new_tokens, ('batch', 't'))

  return new_tokens

example_logits = tf.random.normal([5, 1, output_text_processor.vocabulary_size()])
example_output_tokens = translator.sample(example_logits, temperature=1.0)
example_output_tokens

def translate_unrolled(self,
                       input_text, *,
                       max_length=50,
                       return_attention=True,
                       temperature=1.0):
  batch_size = tf.shape(input_text)[0]
  input_tokens = self.input_text_processor(input_text)
  enc_output, enc_state = self.encoder(input_tokens)

  dec_state = enc_state
  new_tokens = tf.fill([batch_size, 1], self.start_token)

  result_tokens = []
  attention = []
  done = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.bool)

  for _ in range(max_length):
    dec_input = DecoderInput(new_tokens=new_tokens,
                             enc_output=enc_output,
                             mask=(input_tokens!=0))
    
    dec_result, dec_state = self.decoder(dec_input, state=dec_state)

    attention.append(dec_result.attention_weights)

    new_tokens = self.sample(dec_result.logits, temperature)

    # If a sequence produces an `end_token`, set it `done`
    done = done | (new_tokens == self.end_token)
    # Once a sequence is done it only produces 0-padding.
    new_tokens = tf.where(done, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64), new_tokens)

    # Collect the generated tokens
    result_tokens.append(new_tokens)

    if tf.executing_eagerly() and tf.reduce_all(done):
      break

  # Convert the list of generates token ids to a list of strings.
  result_tokens = tf.concat(result_tokens, axis=-1)
  result_text = self.tokens_to_text(result_tokens)

  if return_attention:
    attention_stack = tf.concat(attention, axis=1)
    return {'text': result_text, 'attention': attention_stack}
  else:
    return {'text': result_text}
```

Everything works well, i get the model i want. But when i try loading the model with tensorflow in another file like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

three_input_text = tf.constant([
    # This is my life.
    'Энэ бол миний амьдрал',
    # Are they still home?
    'Тэд гэртээ хэвээрээ юу?',
    # Try to find out.'
    'Үүнийг олж мэдэхийг хичээ.',
])

reloaded = tf.saved_model.load('translator')
result = reloaded.tf_translate(three_input_text)

for tr in result['text']:
  print(tr.numpy().decode())
```

i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4155, in _get_op_def
    return self._op_def_cache[type]
KeyError: 'NormalizeUTF8'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 912, in load_partial
    loader = Loader(object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 151, in __init__
    function_deserialization.load_function_def_library(
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\function_deserialization.py", line 409, in load_function_def_library
    func_graph = function_def_lib.function_def_to_graph(
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function_def_to_graph.py", line 82, in function_def_to_graph
    graph_def, nested_to_flat_tensor_name = function_def_to_graph_def(
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function_def_to_graph.py", line 252, in function_def_to_graph_def
    op_def = default_graph._get_op_def(node_def.op)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4159, in _get_op_def
    pywrap_tf_session.TF_GraphGetOpDef(self._c_graph, compat.as_bytes(type),
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'NormalizeUTF8' in binary running on DESKTOP-GQ7D2QI. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Users\Downloads\Test\Cyrillic\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    reloaded = tf.saved_model.load('translator')
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 782, in load
    result = load_partial(export_dir, None, tags, options)["root"]
  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\CyrillicEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 915, in load_partial
    raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'NormalizeUTF8' in binary running on <computer>. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
 You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.
```

My env:
Windows 10
Python 3.10.4
conda 4.12.0
tensorflow 2.9.0

Can someone explain me this error please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `tensorflow_text` is a dependency, so try to install it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210060/keyerror-normalizeutf8-loading-a-model-to-another-jupyter-notebook).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyError: 'NormalizeUTF8' loading a model to another jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210060/keyerror-normalizeutf8-loading-a-model-to-another-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a little late, but have you tried adding import tensorflow to your file? I got the same error when doing a similar project, turns out I needed to have both tensorflow_text and tensorflow imported and that fixed it.